# Swiper js - How can i make Distance between slides in rem/em/%?

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

Is it possible to make the distance between slides in Swiper js through relative units, for example 2rem?

The whole page works for me completely on relative units. All dimensions are specified in rem, and it in turn depends on the size of the viewport (this is done for total perspective adaptability)

For example:

```
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   outline: none;
   font-size: calc(100vw / 1440 * 8);
}

.swiper-slide {
   display:flex;
   max-width: 33.33%
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: green;
   color:white;
   font-size: 4rem; (this will be 32px)
   padding: 2rem; (It's 16px)
}
```

But then I ran into the distance between the slides...

The documentation says that for `spaceBetween: string | number,` only **string value** is set via js.
*Using css to set an indent to the right of the slide does not work + the documentation warns that this is not worth doing.*

But I already put both margin and removed through nth from the first and last slide. - As expected, it does not work correctly. Namely, the flipping is taking into account the margin. Gap at the wrapper doesn't work either.

I tried to reassign in js through a variable - also without results.

I ask for a helping hand. Here is the sandbox - https://codepen.io/divside/full/eYPKNxN
The task is that the distance between slides should always be 2rem

All... gap/margin/padding/ rem in js/vars... all

Comment: Does setting `spaceBetween: '2rem'` in the JS not work?

Comment: nope. Swiper taking the number only from spaceBetween: '2rem'. So swiper think what is 2px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, spaceBetween is only in px

You could try to stablish a global constant in your js representing how many px is one rem and use that as modifier in javascript

ex.:

```
const rem = 16; // 1 rem is 16px

// rest of the code

spaceBetween: rem * 2,

// more code
```

modified pen: https://codepen.io/Crist-bal-D-az-lvarez/pen/abRKdyP

swiper docs
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-spaceBetween

Updated pen that update value on window resize https://codepen.io/Crist-bal-D-az-lvarez/pen/rNqKGWg

Comment: hmmm. it's good, but it's not recalculated actually than u resize the window.

Comment: So, yeah. Now it's 16*2=32px. But if u will scale down the viewport. For example -2x. Page 2rem should be = 16px.  But in JS it's keeping static (64px)

Comment: Yes, you are right, maybe you won't have to use that property of swiper.js and just leave a margin right to each slide of 2rem with css (selector with :not(:last-child)) or a padding right

Comment: hmmm... i was try that one (thanks for ur example):
var viewWidth = window.innerWidth;
var rem = (viewWidth) / 1440 * 8; // 1rem is 8px

spaceBetween: rem * 4,

AND IT'S WORKS!!! But... it's work only before u'll resize the viewport. I mean it's still fixed value. But if u'll refresh the page - it's will be a new value. So it's almost done bro. How many people trying to find a solution like that one...:)

Can u please help me make a resize function? I'm so low in js.

Comment: Great, in that case you can listen to window resize event and recalculate the variable (cannot be constant anymore) and at the same point, refresh swiper to sync with the new vale https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event (sorry I am afk and i can't update the demo right now)

Comment: i was try tis one:

`code
function setSize() {
  var viewWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var rem = (viewWidth) / 1440 * 8; // 1rem is 8px
  return rem;
}

var resultRem = setSize('');

setSize();

window.addEventListener('resize', setSize);
window.onresize = setSize;


var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: false,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: resultRem * 4,
`

But it's not working. Only if refresh the page. 
https://codepen.io/divside/full/JjmZXbY

Comment: I have added a new pen with the update

Comment: damn bro, it works. But why u add the timer? It correct to do like that:
'code function windowResize() {
  pageRem = window.innerWidth / 1440 * 8; // 1rem is 8px
      swiper.params.spaceBetween = pageRem * 4;
      swiper.update();
}'

Comment: Yes, it is only for performance, you can remove it if you want

Answer (score 0):

example
you can set `margin: 0 1.2rem` to your slide elements
and set `margin: 0 -2.4rem` to your swiper-wrapper
and everything will work